Is there a way in windows to split my monitor in multiple monitors (not just virtal desktops i can switch between, nor docking windows)
I have a large screen instead of multiple screens, i always preferred that and docking windows in either 2X split or 4X (or rarely 2X and then 2X again on another side) but sometimes i want to run a game or something alike that only runs in fullscreen.
i'm on a 4K monitor and i'd want to be able to say "switch to splitting my desktop in a way that it is recognized as 4X monitors" so that i can send what i want to the monitor of my choice, or better yet anything flexible that lets me create a virtual monitor and place it wherever i want. Does such a thing exist?
Searching with basic keywords yields results about splitting my windows or about creating virtual monitors that you can switch to / are out of view but i want multiple of them visible at once on the real monitor / even better if they're movable (monitor in borderless window).
Question is for windows 11 latest.

I have done this under Win7/XP.  It needed DVI input to the monitor.

@Chenmunka i'm not sure i understand you / how the monitor input would be relevant, can you expand?

You need a monitor that has multiple inputs and support picture in picture. If you then hook up more inputs to the same system, the monitor can allow you to treat sections of the monitor as one monitor

@LPChip that's not what i'm looking for, i'm looking for a software only solution that would expose a virtual monitor as a device driver and then display that on the main window in a way i can arrange it as i wish (basically hardware picture in picture, without the hardware nor touching any monitor buttons and with ability to drag and drop within windows / move anywhere etc)

I'm explaining the first comment. Do note, asking for a software recommendation is considered Off-topic. Please see the help-center to learn what kind of question you can ask.

@LPChip oh oki i didn't realise you refered to the first comment. I'm not asking for a specific software recommendation, more of if any such solution already exists as i never pondered it (be it built into windows in a way i don't know off etc), when i say software solution i mean by oposition of hardware i'm not asking for recommendation to software X more like if there is a category of software i could look for or if nothing like that exists because it is hard to search for (due to close but not quite what i want being legion).

writing question as stream of thought not likely to get help

You may not feel your question is asking that we recommend a particular software solution, but your question is asking for exactly that: "does such a thing exist", and your comments double down on this. I believe there's software that can partition your display based on your preferences. But, like others have said, this sort of question is specifically off topic.

What about using the Windows native "Remote Desktop" feature?

Activate Windows Remote desktop (locally). You may take any tutorials on internet on how to do it. For example this very first link when i google it: https://thinstuff.com/products/xpvs-server/enable-remote-desktop-windows-11/

Configure your Remote Desktop to allow yourself (your user) to connect locally (127.0.0.1)

configure your system to allow multiple interactive sessions per user. This can be done using the Group Policy Editor or the Terminal Services Configuration tool, depending on your version of Windows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1193136/logged-in-with-same-user-twice-in-remote-desktop-c

To connect to the PC locally (127.0.0.1), open the Remote Desktop
Connection application on your PC (search from the start menu). Enter '127.0.0.1' as name/IP addr. When connecting, You will be prrobably prompted to enter your username and password.

Now you should have a completely resizable and customizable Windows Desktop. You may move it and resize it in your monitor screen at wish :). I took this picture fom internet on how this should look like for you: https://store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.62023.9007199266246189.c0918962-fce1-4c21-b642-a356243c62f7.1b6cf335-2fda-4038-860e-31a621a47d0f


Security concern:
By default, Windows 11 will only allow remote connections from any devices in your local network (with the correct username/password given).
If you want to reduce it to your PC only (127.0.0.1), you should consider configuring your router/firewall accordingly.
Happy gaming on your half-screen! :)

I don't think that would work as remote desktop logs you off from your physical session? Or is there a setting tobypass that? And if it does that would still be the same single screen i'm remote desktoping into so it would only do an infinite desktop view? I may be getting this wrong though so if it's possible to virtual desktop on another desktop on the same account without being logged off that might actually be just the solution i needed.

Fair point. See my updated answer. You may enable multiple interactive session per user (this is configurable in GPO..see the link). Basically, when opening an RDP, this should  prevent you from logging off, as well as allowing you to open a DIFFERENT session. So you should not face infinite desktop view as this would open a different desktop)

Alternate way, if you don't get to allow multiple sessions per user, would be to create a second account and simply rdp to it.

It's not quite what i want but might be a reasonable option if there is no better one, another session is not quite another monitor since i can't just move the mouse to/from it to have it captured and RDP is not exactly real time performance but for the things i have in mind it could work as a workaround, i was more of hoping there would be a way to simulate a screen (presented to windows as HW) and copy-render that into a window or a solution of that kind
